# Check if a channel is a voice channel (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im making a suggestion system but when you set the suggestion channel to a voice channel and make a suggestion the whole script errors.So i want to know if theres a way to tell the diffrence between a text channel and voice channel so if its a voice channel then i wanna return. But i dont know how to check if a channel is a voice or text channel.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `Channel.type` object to determine whether it is a voice channel or not.

First, we want to get the channel, using either the `.get()` or `.find()` functions, and then check the channel's type using a simple `if` statement:

```
const channelObject = message.guild.channels.cache.get('channel id here'); // Gets the channel object
if (channelObject.type === 'voice') return; // Checks if the channel type is voice
```