# How do you get a random voice channel ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord chatbot, but something I would like it to do is to join a random voice channel. I have tried the following from a different example, but you need to specify a channel ID. Which doesn’t suit my needs.

```js
const channel = message.guild.channels.get('voiceChannelID');
```

I've also tried this from [Check if a channel is a voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65616957/check-if-a-channel-is-a-voice-channel-discord-js) but it also requires a specific channel ID.

```js
const channelObject = message.guild.channels.cache.get('channel id here'); // Gets the channel object
if (channelObject.type === 'voice') return; // Checks if the channel type is voice
```

It would be greatly appreciated if you could answer with some code that would find a random voice channel.

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: It actually turns out I was using v12, i guess I’ll upgrade to v13 now…

Comment: I've just noticed that you unaccepted my answer. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: No, nothing wrong with it. I thought i could mark both as a solution. But I didn’t realize it removed it from yours. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) all channels, [`filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) them by their [`type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=type) and use [`Collection#random()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=random) to pick a random one from the returned collection:

```js
let channels = await message.guild.channels.fetch();
let voiceChannels = channels.filter(ch => ch.type === 'GUILD_VOICE');
let randomVoiceChannel = voiceChannels.random();
```

Please note that in discord.js v13, `VoiceChannel#type` is `GUILD_VOICE` instead of `voice`. For more info [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71748308/6126373).

---

*Update:* If you're using discord.js v12, you can use the following:

```js
let channels = message.guild.channels.cache;
let voiceChannels = channels.filter((ch) => ch.type === 'voice');
let randomVoiceChannel = voiceChannels.random();
```

<sup><sub>... and it's probably time to upgrade :)</sub></sup>

Answer (score -1):

I've had to grab all of the channels and filter out the voice channels before, so I just grabbed that code and flipped it around and added some random to it.

What I did:

```
let channels = Array.from(message.guild.channels.cache.keys());
const c = channels.filter(v => message.guild.channels.resolve(v).isVoice() == true);
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * c.length);
const randomVoiceChannel = c[index];
```

The first line grabs all of the channels in the server.

The 2nd line removes the non-voice channels.

And finally the last 2 lines generate a random index from the array and outputs a value.

```
const randomVoiceChannel = Array.from(message.guild.channels.cache.keys()).filter(v => message.guild.channels.resolve(v).isVoice() == true)
[Math.floor(Math.random() * Array.from(message.guild.channels.cache.keys()).filter(v => message.guild.channels.resolve(v).isVoice() == true).length)];
```

nifty 1-liner (please don't use this its incredibly unreadable I just thought it was funny)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Unfortunately the first answer returns
`TypeError: message,guild.channels.fetch is not a function.`

And the second one returns 
`Reference Error: interaction is not defined`

Comment: @abcdefgh Please, next time write on these answers separately. I don't get a notification if instead of my post you send a response here.

Comment: Oh sorry. I’m not sure how to add a comment for both of your answers.

Comment: im so sorry i made a bunch of typos because for some reason i couldnt just copy paste from my testing environment, and i was using interactions instead of message